# soldify not having even thickness

Tags: modifiers

I have a simple cube. And deleted front and back faces. I added solidify modifier. Will i tried all the options. Cant get the even thickness. Rotation scale & faces are oriented out. What else missing. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLDkH.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually want even thickness, here, (the slice is thicker along its vertex normals than the other walls). If you select 'Complex' as the *Mode* in the modifier, then *Boundary Shape* becomes available, and it has a 'Flat' option.

[image]

Comment: Damned! Yes this new option! Very nice Mr Betts!

Comment: @lemon I wish the modifiers could work off custom normals, though? I've never got that to work?

Comment: Yes same though recently.... maybe due to the order in which normals are considered? I mean between geometrical part and shading part (if they are effectively different)?

Comment: Though, considering the answer, wall thickness is not even (left/right compared to top/bottom)

Comment: @lemon, Yup. But it _is_ like  a slice taken through an even-walled (with respect to face-normals) box. Geometrically impossible to have even walls _and_ a flat slice..

Comment: Was thinking about even thikness (former modfier option) + boolean on each side... but surely another story here.

Comment: The thickness as compare my other parts not to thin. I have given same thickness (1cm) to it. Why there is difference of the thickness with the above mesh. https://imgur.com/a/y4jOm0A. here is the file with different thickness [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4Pya60QL" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4Pya60QL/)

Comment: Hi. @atek You're right. I guess I/you should edit this answer? _Complex_ + _Flat_ + _Constraints_ works for me, giving even thickness of 1cm on the vertical sides.and the right 'sliced' thickness on the horizontal sides.But to make that a proper answer, I feel I should reverse-engineer or find from the code what the _Constraints_ algorithm actually is.  As usual, in the user manual, it's only described in hand-wavy terms.